# No puedo conseguir desencriptar mensaje, AES - SHA-256 - SecretKeySpec , "Tecnicas de programacion segura" Java en NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, seguridad

Estoy haciendo ejercicios sobre "TÉCNICAS DE
PROGRAMACIÓN SEGURA".

**Problema:**

El mensaje a descifrar es una String de 4 numeros (ejemplo: "0000"), únicamente se sabe que para generarlo se ha usado una clave AES de 192 bits, basada en una contraseña generada mediante el algoritmo SHA-256. Puntos a tratar:

• Obtener un hash de la contraseña (un String) con el algoritmo "SHA-256".

• Copiar con el método Arrays.copyOf los 192 bits a un array de bytes
(192/8 bytes)

• Utilizar la clase SecretKeySpec para generar una clave a partir del array
de bytes.

Pide: "Haga un programa que le permita averiguar el contenido del mensaje original." La codificación en binario del mensaje interceptado, escrita como secuencia de
valores hexadecimales, es la variable "enc".

**Puntos de mi código:**

Como se trata de "romper un mensaje cifrado por fuerza bruta" utilizo un FOR para crear la STRING deseada con unos simples IF, para obtener todas las posibles combinaciones de 4 numero en una String.
Después creo un resumen del STRING generado, porque como utiliza la SHA-256. Lo cifro y cuando compruebo el resumen cifrado de la STRING que genera el bucle con el resumen a adivinar, ninguna es capaz. No se que tengo mal la verdad.

`public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        byte[] enc = {(byte) 0x24, (byte) 0xE9, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x38,
            (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xA1, (byte) 0x8E, (byte) 0x4B,
            (byte) 0x7D, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x55,
            (byte) 0x4C, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0x7D, (byte) 0x47};
        byte[] cifrado = Arrays.copyOf(enc, 192);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            String profString = "";
            if (i < 10) {
                profString = profString.concat("000").concat(String.valueOf(i));
            } else if (i < 100) {
                profString = profString.concat("00").concat(String.valueOf(i));
            } else if (i < 1000) {
                profString = profString.concat("0").concat(String.valueOf(i));
            } else {
                profString = profString.concat(String.valueOf(i));
            }

            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            md.update(profString.getBytes());
            byte profResumen[] = md.digest();

            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(profResumen, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            byte[] profCifrado= cipher.doFinal(Arrays.copyOf(profResumen, 192));

            if (md.isEqual(cifrado, profCifrado)) {
                System.out.println("True");
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }`

Segundo Post. Muchas gracias de antemano, e intentado hacer el post lo mejor posible, cualquier critica constructiva es bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si le interesa a alguien encontré como solucionarlo.

Antes que nada, el planteamiento es lo mas importante, y si eso esta mal, todo estará mal. En mi caso el mío era que yo tenia un mensaje cifrado, y este mensaje se cifró con una contraseña. Entonces yo planeé que comparando las claves cifradas si eran iguales, iba a ser true, ¡pero mal!. Es imposible, porque para eso tengo que saber el mensaje original.

Lo que se tiene que ver es conseguir la contraseña para descifrar el mensaje, entonces cambie el metodo a esto:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    byte[] enc = {(byte) 0x24, (byte) 0xE9, (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x38,
        (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xA1, (byte) 0x8E, (byte) 0x4B,
        (byte) 0x7D, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0x55,
        (byte) 0x4C, (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0x7D, (byte) 0x47};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        //Genera de "0000" al "9999".
        String proofString = String.format("%04d", i);

        //Realizado del resumen con el String generado.
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        messageDigest.update(proofString.getBytes());
        byte[] proofBytes = messageDigest.digest();
        
        byte[] proofConvertByte = Arrays.copyOf(proofBytes, 192 / 8);

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(proofConvertByte, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        
        try {
            byte[] proofDeCipher = cipher.doFinal(enc);
            System.out.println("Posible clave= " + proofString + ", mensaje que descrifrada= " + new String(proofDeCipher));
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        }
    }
```

Como vemos, lo primero que cambio es el metodo de generar las **strings**, despues lo que cambio en el numero de bits, de 192 a 192/8, fallo importante y tontisimo. Después desencriptamos la clave e intentamos descifrar el mensaje.

Lo que no se, es porque existen diferentes candidatos a descifrar, pero solo con una el mensaje es legible. Espero que le ayude a alguien.